# Remove new lines adding to encoded string - OkHttp

Tags: android, okhttp, image-upload

I'm trying to upload an image to the server. I'm using okhttp library.

```
RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .addPart(RequestBody.create(null, encodedImage))
            .build();
```

When server receives this, It includes;

> --a99c15b4-7ae0-4792-ad8d-7f371d2d59ab\r\nContent-Length: 69053\r\n\r\n ...
>   \n\r\n--c3014d15-5428-4e08-9052-9c603464315d--

at the both begining and end of the encoded string.

Is there a way to stop adding these lines to the encodedString in client side?

Comment: Those are HTTP headers.  You want them added.  Content-Length is the length of the data attached.

Comment: yeah, but the server side reject those. It only accept the encoded string.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's kind of late (3 years haha), but I had a similar problem and came up with a solution. So I'd left it here, just in case anyone would need it.

This -- stuff is called *boundary* and it generates automatically for each MultipartBody to determine the beginning and the end of the request body, so you can be sure you got the whole message, as it can be really long and may consist of many Parts.
Content-Length at the beginning of the message notifies server about how many data it is supposed to receive, it kind of prevents you from data losses too.

To eliminate adding all this text, you can simply create your own RequestBody implementation, like this:

```
        val body = object : RequestBody() {
            @Nullable
            override fun contentType(): MediaType? = null

            @Throws(IOException::class)
            override fun writeTo(sink: BufferedSink) {
                file.source().use { source -> sink.writeAll(source) }
            }
        }
```

MultipartBody does the same thing under the hood, but besides this, it adds a lot of other stuff, like boundary, content length and each separate Part.